# Tabs structure working in jquery 2.1.3, showing error in 3.6.0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=#technical]

**tabs.js files**

```
$(function() {
    var tab = $('.tab a'),
        content = $('.tab-content');
    if ( location.hash ){
        tab.filter('[href='+location.hash+']').addClass('active');
        content.hide().filter(location.hash).show().fadeIn();
    }   else    {   
        tab.filter(':first').addClass('active');
        content.filter(':not(:first)').hide();
    }
    tab.click(function(){
        if( location.hash ){
            var id = location.hash;
        }   else    {
            var id = $(this).attr('href');
        }
        tab.removeClass('active').filter('[href='+id+']').addClass('active');
        content.hide().filter(id).show();
    });
    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
        tab.trigger('click');
    });
});
```

**tabs.php files**

```
<div class="tab">
    <a href="#overview">Overview</a>
    <a href="#features">Features</a>
    <a href="#articles">Articles</a>
    <a href="#technical">Technical</a>
</div>


    <div id="overview"  class="tab-content">
    <p>echo..</p>
    </div>
    <div id="features"  class="tab-content">
    <p>echo..</p>
    </div>  
    <div id="articles"  class="tab-content">
    <p>echo..</p>
    </div>       
    <div id="technical" class="tab-content">
    <p>echo..</p>
    </div>
```

Why am I having such a problem? It works when I activate the old version, but when I try to update I have a problem. thank you

Comment: You need to wrap the attribute value in quotes as it contains a `#` character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a Quote issue. You have:

```
tab.removeClass('active').filter('[href='+id+']').addClass('active');
```

So the Selector become:

```
[href=#overview]
```

I believe you want to correct the selector to the following:

```
[href='#overview']
```

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var tab = $('.tab a'),
    content = $('.tab-content');
  if (location.hash) {
    tab.filter("[href='" + location.hash + "']").addClass('active');
    content.hide().filter(location.hash).show().fadeIn();
  } else {
    tab.filter(':first').addClass('active');
    content.filter(':not(:first)').hide();
  }
  tab.click(function() {
    if (location.hash) {
      var id = location.hash;
    } else {
      var id = $(this).attr('href');
    }
    tab.removeClass('active').filter("[href='" + id + "']").addClass('active');
    content.hide().filter(id).show();
  });
  $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    tab.trigger('click');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="tab">
  <a href="#overview">Overview</a>
  <a href="#features">Features</a>
  <a href="#articles">Articles</a>
  <a href="#technical">Technical</a>
</div>


<div id="overview" class="tab-content">
  <p>echo..</p>
</div>
<div id="features" class="tab-content">
  <p>echo..</p>
</div>
<div id="articles" class="tab-content">
  <p>echo..</p>
</div>
<div id="technical" class="tab-content">
  <p>echo..</p>
</div>
```

this does not generate the error you reported.

Answer (score 1):

**Jquery 3.0 deprecated bind function**

```js
  // your code 

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
        tab.trigger('click');
    });

   // change to 
    $(window).on('hashchange', function(){
        tab.trigger('click');
    });
```